# CodeMirror Merge constructor on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I am using CodeMirror and the merge addon to compare some edited code with an original document. In a normal view (not a merge view) I can add a listener to the CodeMirror constructor to listen for changes and give the user visual feedback to show that the changes have not been saved yet.

Like so:

```
//codemirror constructor
var cmConstructor = CodeMirror(target, setOptions());
cmConstructor.on('change', function() {codeChange(variables)});
```

Now when I call it on a merge constructor like so:

```
//codemirror merge constructor
var cmConstructor = CodeMirror.MergeView(target, setOptions());
cmConstructor.on('change', function() {codeChange(variables)});
```

I get the following error:
    Uncaught TypeError: `Object #<Object> has no method 'on'`

Any idea how I can listen for changes within a mergeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MergeView` encapsulates two (or three) editors, you can get at the editors with the `.editor()`, `.leftOriginal()` and `.rightOriginal()` methods. In this case, since the originals don't change, you want

```
mergeView.editor().on("change", function(cm, change) { ... });
```